# Most secure way to store secrets while building a docker image (Python flask server)

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables

So currently I am building a docker image for my python flask server, and the way that I am accessing the secret variable inside the code is
`app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("todo_secret_key") or "secret"`

Now if I want to run the code without the container, I'd use export command(linux) to temporarily have the secret key in the environment, but I need it to be in the environment of the container.

Now, a few methods that I am aware of are

1. Pass it with -e in the docker run command `docker run {imageName} -e {name}={value}` (insecure as I dont want it to be in terminal logs)
2. Pass it in the dockerfile by specifying the environment variable (definitely insecure as this file would be public)

Apart from these methods, is there a more secure way to pass the variable

P.s It is my first time buidling an image so apologies if it is a silly question

Comment: There's a whole branch of operations that talks about the best way to do this called "Configuration management"

Comment: `--env-file ...`?

Comment: As a good-natured aside: I really appreciate questions like this that are concise, to the point, and describe an asker who is but moments from realizing the sheer scale of the iceberg they've just discovered is dead ahead.

Comment: whatever the approach, you could still print the environment variables. So why are you concerned about it. Please elaborate.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy true, but `docker run ... -e name=secret` is visible from any user's `ps aux`, even if that user does not have permissions to exec into the container.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy Yes,you can print environment variables, but these environment variables are going to be injected directly into the container(during runtime), so unless an attacker gets access to that running container, he/she won't be able to view the environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to tie your runtime configuration to your build time configuration much too tightly if you're worrying about this *as* you're building your docker image!

Remember that these are discrete, if interconnected, stages.

Develop -> Build -> Test -> Deploy -> Test (Non-functional) -> repeat...

No stage should dictate what future stages do. `docker build` is the "Build" stage, and so should have no idea what configuration is correct in the environment for when the image is eventually deployed. How could it? That configuration could change over time!

Instead, look to [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) to handle these sorts of decisions. Your docker scheduler (Kubernetes is common, but other flyweight executors like Docker Swarm or ECS should do this too) should have a way to read a configuration file and inject it into the environment. A full discussion of configuration management could (and has) filled textbooks.

Comment: Alright, so even if I do build my image and send in the configuration parameters later, I would still like to know what is the most secure way to pass the configuration options during runtime ( -e with a run command , orr my mounting the files as a volume .... or any other alternatives? )
P.s, I'm not using any orchestration tools, I will just be using docker-compose

Comment: @jmvaswani a common refrain with answers about security will be "It depends." Where are you running the code? If it's just a developer machine, then it doesn't matter if it's secure. If it's running in the cloud, then you have to ask about your threat vectors (so what if they can discover the secret in the terminal if any terminal access means you're already boned). In general, I would probably include a [.env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) in the machine image running the docker container.